# Botfront errno 13 permission denied

Tags: permissions, rasa, errno

hi i am trying to train the rasa chatbot in Botfront. [The Error im geting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKcN6.png) while trying to train the Chatbot I’m getting an error: errno 13 permission denied for a file under the models folder. First i thou it was an resolut of using an  custom action but even if I’m not using the custom action I’m still getting the error.

I am greatfull for any tips.

I tryed to use just simple dialogus.